# jQuery Mobile: how to bind plugin with a div fetched via Ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, plugins

I'm trying to add a DatePicker plugin to a JQM app. Everything works when the HTML code is static in my app but when I pull the HTML via Ajax the plugin cease to initialize (I checked and all the plugin files loads to browser and there is no error in console, just nothing happens).

I'm sure this happens because plugin expects a HTML tag to hold on to ("input" in this case) which is not there onload - it shows when the Ajax fetches it from server file which takes a second.

The code is simple.

The plugin (this is pulled by Ajax into the HTML file):

```
<input type="text" data-field="datetime" readonly>
<div id="dateBox"></div> // space for plugin's calendar
```

Plugin init:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#page-id-where-input-is-appended', function() {           
  $("#dateBox").DateTimePicker(); 
});
```

I suppose that solving this problem means to use appropriate JQM method when initializing. I used pageshow, and few different methods that works after the page DOM is ready - from pageinit to pagechange. With now success.

Any tips?

Comment: Are you loading an external page?

Comment: I'm loading few HTML elements from php file (echo output), including the plugin input.

Comment: How do you load them? What method are you using? Are you including JS library within html elements?

Comment: I use typical jquery $.ajax method (POST type). JS library is added in html file so it's not loaded with ajax.

Comment: Have you tried calling $("#dateBox").DateTimePicker(); inn the ajax response after adding the input to the page?

Comment: @ezanker Yes I did and it worked. Thanks for posting maybe someone will find this tip helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<input type="text" data-field="datetime" id="calendar_box" readonly>
<div id="dateBox"></div>

$(document).on('pageshow', '#page-id-where-input-is-appended', function() {           
  $("#calendar_box").DateTimePicker(); 
});
```

Comment: It still does not the thing unfortunately. I'm not sure if pageshow is the right one here.